# How much damage do vehicle weapons vs. personal size chars

Tags: damage, vehicles, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

Planetary scale armor is 10x personal scale armor according to the rulebook. But I didn't find any statement about the damage itself. Is this also taken by x10?

Thus if a starship or speeder with light blasters (4 damage) fires at a personal scale target is that then 40 damage?  or "just" 4 damage and the soak of the target is divided by 10 before substraction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In Force and Destiny, the weapon deals 40 damage

[Force and Destiny](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/star-wars-force-and-destiny/info) clarifies on p230

> When dealing with a vessel's weapons, armor, and hull trauma threshold, every point is equal to 10 points of the equivalent characteristic in personal scale. For example, **a laser cannon with a bade damage of 3, mounted to a starfighter, deals 3 points of damage when fired at another spacecraft, but 30 points of damage when fired at a human.** Conversely, a human-sized blaster rifle would need to deal 10 points of damage to a starship to inflict even 1 point of damage on it.